# ROS Answers SE migration: Navigation

Tags: rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have obtained a map using RTAB-Map. Now I want to use the point cloud obtained to navigate from a place in the map to the required goal created using the Kinect XBOX 360 and RTAB-Map. Please suggest how should I do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275410/navigation/) by [paper](https://answers.ros.org/users/28823/paper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-11-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, this is a quite common task that is solved with the ROS Navigation Stack (http://wiki.ros.org/navigation)
You can install it like this:

`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-navigation`

assuming you have Ros Indigo installed, if you have Kinetic, just change it to kinetic.

Since you have a Kinect XBOX you also want to look into the Turtlebot navigation package (http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation)

You'll end up with something looking like this:
[image: image description]

But for that t happen you need to convert your pointcloud to a laserscan, good luck for you there is a package for that ;)
Check it here: http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan

Afterwards, you use the navigation stack and create your map with the laser scan, it'll be as easy as publishing a 2D Nav Goal for your robot to navigate. Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0